# ui-router how to define multiple views in multiple modules for same state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angular-ui-router

I devide my application into separate modules. And now i need to make config in each module to define states for ui-router.

The issue is i want to show in same state (for instance "index") in different named views components from separate modules. But it is nessesary to define chancks of state.views inside multiple modules.

Here example i want to do:

```
angular.module("a",[])
  .config(
     ....
      .state("index",{
        url: '/'
        views: {
          "main": componentA
        }
      }
  )


angular.module("b",[])
  .config(
     ....
      .state("index",{
        url: '/'
        views: {
          "aside": componentB
        }
      }
  )
```

Comment: At the end you have to have one main module where you put all others, once you do that, all configs are merged, and it will not allow you to have multiple states with the same name. I'm not sure what you want to achieve, can you please provide a bit more info.

Comment: I haveindex.html devided with blocks: header sidebar content and footer  ... i need to place content from different modules inside this blocks the same time (i.e in one state). I can do it with multiple named views. But i have to define this route in one place. The issue is i want to define this state inside separate modules.

Comment: You do not need different modules to have different templates. Even if you have to (want to), you do not need multiple states, just multiple views inside one template, that will be served  under one state, in this case `index.html`